# Can't update Git project

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble pulling from Git, using Update Project in IntelliJ, it says

```
Can't update No tracked branch configured
```

and gave me the suggestion to use `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin` so I can track it, problem is I already did that, I went to Bash and typed the line, it said it was now tracking my origin branch, so I tried to update on IntelliJ again, and it keeps saying `Can't update`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, there are several git roots in the project, and the tracking is not set in one of them. Update project tries updating all roots in the project and fails if there is no tracking branch in one of them.